# Getting Snmpwalk Timeout Error for AIX Server

Tags: snmp, aix

I am trying to run the batch file which will do snmp walk for two AIX server. Here the problem is for the first device the walk is completed successfully but for the second device it is throwing "SNMP Timeout Error".

I have tried using the batch file which i created and using snmpwalk.exe. In snmpwalk.exe for both device the walk is happening but through batch file the device which is processing first will give the correct result and for the second one it is throwing timeout error.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\test\snmpwalk.exe" -v3 -u test -a MD5 -A XXX -x DES -X YYY 172.21.20.19 .1.3 


"C:\Program Files (x86)\test\snmpwalk.exe" -v3 -u test -a MD5 -A XXX -x DES -X ZZZ 172.21.20.21 .1.3
```

Comment: If you asked: _Why do I get timeout error?_ the answerd would be: _Probably networking problem._

Answer (score 0):

In environment where multiple devices enabled with SNMP, the snmpEngineID must be unique as it is the [unique identifier](http://oidref.com/1.3.6.1.6.3.10.2.1.1).

In some cases, using cloned devices creates duplicate snmpEngineID in network results in above mentioned behavior (i.e., throwing SNMP timeout). In order to avoid this, do reset the hostID once cloned. [Reference](https://support.zenoss.com/hc/en-us/articles/208412236-Duplicate-EngineIDs-Cause-SNMPv3-Timeouts-During-Monitoring).